# How to select all columns except one in Yii2?

Tags: mysql, yii2

What I need to do is to select all the database columns except one.

I have something like:

```
$foo = self::find()
  ->select([
     self::tableName() . '.*'
]);
```

It's selecting all the columns, but how to do that one column wouldn't be selected? Obviously I can tell to select a specific columns like this:

```
$foo = self::find()
  ->select([
      self::tableName() . '.column1',
      self::tableName() . '.column2',
      self::tableName() . '.column3'
      ...
  ]);
```

But the database table is really big, so I'm looking for a proper way to do it..

Any ideas? Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

You need not mention `self::tableName() . '.column1',` all the time.
You can just add all the fileds in your db table in the model and use them as follows.

Your model should contain method for returning fields,something like this

```
   public function fields() {
    return[
        'id',
        'column1',
        'column2',
        'column3',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
         etc...
    ];
}
```

Then You can just call the fields into the query like

```
$foo = self::find()
->select([
  'column1',
  'column2',
  'column3',
  ...
```

]);

Now, coming to your question, we can just call all the fields as `self::fields()`, which returns a array of fields in your table.
Then, you can remove that specific field from the array we got,by doing something like this

```
if (($key = array_search('strawberry', $array)) !== false) {
unset($array[$key]);
```

}

Then, we have the sorted array without the field that is not required.

Now, you pass the sorted array to the Query as

```
$foo = self::find()
  ->select([
  $array
 ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As variant you can try to form column list dynamically and use it

```
// variant 1
$columns = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'user' AND table_schema = database()")->queryAll();

$out_columns = [];

foreach ($columns as $item) {
   if (! in_array($item['column_name'], ['auth_key', 'password_hash', 'password_reset_token'])) {
       $out_columns[] = $item['column_name'];
   }
}

print_r($out_columns);

print_r(User::find()->select($out_columns)->one());



// variant 2
$columns = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'user' AND column_name NOT IN('auth_key', 'password_hash', 'password_reset_token') AND table_schema = database()")->queryAll();

$out_columns = [];

foreach ($columns as $item) {
   $out_columns[] = $item['column_name'];
}

print_r($out_columns);

print_r(User::find()->select($out_columns)->one());
```